# MSAL Login popup is not working in - MSTeams Desktop and Mobile Application

Tags: microsoft-teams, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

We are getting this error `Error: Uncaught (in promise): BrowserAuthError: user_cancelled: User cancelled the flow. BrowserAuthError: user_cancelled: User cancelled the flow.`

This error occurs in the MSTeams desktop applications while it's working fine in the browser.

Following is the code snippet for the reference,

```js
const silentRequest = {
            scopes:['openid', 'profile'],
            loginHint:'EMAIL_ADDRESS',
            domainHint:'DOMAIN_HINT'
          };

await this.msalService.loginPopup(silentRequest).toPromise();
```

We would really appreciate your help, thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to launch a popup from within Teams - it's blocked for security reasons. Fortunately, there's a capability specifically built into Teams to handle authentication - it launches a popup -for you-, which them can implement a -redirect- flow within that popup. It's all part of the overall tab SSO capability, and works well when you follow the guidance - see here for an excellent starting point, released just a few weeks ago: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kruUnaZgQaY

Here's a blog form of the video: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/microsoft365dev/lets-decode-single-sign-on-sso-in-microsoft-teams-tabs/

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. It seems like this tutorial is for B2B SSO authentication flow and we have already implemented that in the previous release.

However, we are now migrating to B2C SSO authentication flow for that we understand that user has to login minimum once before requesting `ssoSilent`.

To achieve that we are trying to open the `login popup` which is causing the above issue in Desktop and Mobile app.

Comment: You should update your question then to reflect B2C. In any case, opening your own popup is against recommendations. for instance see "You should not open the authentication pop-up automatically because this is likely to trigger the browser's pop-up blocker as well as confuse the user." and "Azure AD, like most identity providers, does not allow its content to be placed in an iframe." from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/auth-tab-aad (continued below)

Comment: Have a look at the image here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/auth-flow-tab and see how Teams will launch it's own popup for you, as I said in my answer - you end up doing a -redirect- flow from the -hosted- popup. I believe you should look at `microsoftTeams.authentication.authenticate` on the JS SDK to do this - see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/auth-tab-aad

Comment: @RiteshThakkar Yes, please have a look at the doc shared here. You should get the answer you are looking for.

Comment: @HunaidHanfee-MSFT thank you for providing the details and it's worked for me.

Comment: Glad to hear it's working! Please don't forgot to Mark as Answer, so others with a similar problem in future can see how to get help.